# Dynamically Filtering Posts by Data Points - Any Pointers?

Tags: customization, filters

I'm trying to have my wp frontpage display dynamically filterable content (pages/posts links) selectable by the user e.g. country, cost.

It's for a solo female travel blog, the closest thing I've found is the frontpage of [nomadlist.com](http://nomadlist.com)

Would I be best doing this with custom php and custom tables in the same wp or another database? I can't fathom how best to this within wordpress or find any plugin capability implementing it.

Any pointers would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to achieve what you want is to use custom fields and meta query linked with a WP Query and Ajax. You can find the documentation here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

An example of a WP_Query with meta_query :

```
new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('post_links', 'page'),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'cost' => array(
            'key' => 'cost',
            'value' => '500',
            'compare' => '<=',
        ),
        'country' => array(
            'key' => 'country',
            'compare' => 'France',
        ), 
        'city' => array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 
        'cost' => 'ASC',
        'city' => 'ASC',
    ),
));
```

Another way to do it as you way is another table to stock data, depends of your needs and the quantity of data you've to stock.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you for that :0)